# AWS CLI - Bash script to manage instances

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to run a shadowsocks server on AWS ( I live in China and this is the best solution in order to use google ... )

I have already set up [everything on my VM instance](https://www.vpndada.com/how-to-setup-shadowsocks-server-on-amazon-ec2/) the only issue is when the VM restart also the ip change so I have to manually setup my shadowsock client configuration with the new ip.

- How can I manage instances using a bash script ?
  For example getting this infos: public ip, status or start/stop the instance ?

Comment: Just Google aws-cli

Comment: pip install awscli will get you the cli. Play with that.

Comment: sorry I wrote this question just to share the solution I have already implemented

Answer (score 1):

Having AWS cli installed on your system you can use the following script as example.

**Get the instances id**
You can get a list of all instances ids (for the current configured area):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId
```

**Here the script**

- put it in a file (ex `aws_i.sh`) and make it executable.
- run it using one of the following option `status|start|stop|ip|shadow`

Last one `shadow` it just rewrites my shadowsocks client config with the my `ec2` instance's ip

```
 #!/bin/bash

INSTANCE_ID="YOUR_INSTANCE"

function _log(){
    trailbefore=$2
    start=""
    if [ -z $trailbefore ] || [ $trailbefore = true ]
        then
        start=" - "
    fi

    printf "$start$1"
}

function run_command (){
    COMMAND=$1
    # note in the original parameter count as new parameter
    QUERY="$2 $3"
    OUTPUT="--output text"
    local result=$(eval aws ec2 $COMMAND --instance-ids $INSTANCE_ID $QUERY $OUTPUT)
    echo "$result"
}

function getStatus(){
    CMD="describe-instances"
    EXTRA="--query \"Reservations[].Instances[].State[].Name\""
    result=$(run_command $CMD $EXTRA)
    echo $result
}

function _checkStatus(){
    status=$(getStatus)
    if [ $status = "pending" ] || [ $status = "stopping" ]
        then
        _log "Current status: $status"
        _log " Wating "
        while [ $status = "pending" ] || [ $status = "stopping" ]
            do
            sleep 5
            _log "." false
            status=$(getStatus)
        done
        _log "\n" false
    fi
}

function getIp(){
    CMD="describe-instances"
    EXTRA="--query \"Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress\""
    _checkStatus

    if [ $status = "running" ]
        then
        ip=$(run_command $CMD $EXTRA)
        if [ -z "$ip" ]
            then
            _log "Wating for ip "
            while [ -z "$ip" ]
                do
                _log "." false
                sleep 5
                ip=$(run_command $CMD $EXTRA)
            done
        fi
        ## return value
        echo $ip
    else
        _log "Instance not runnning, please start it \n"
    fi

}

function start {
    CMD="start-instances"
    _checkStatus
    result=$(run_command $CMD)
    echo $result
}
function stop {
    CMD="stop-instances"
    _checkStatus
    result=$(run_command $CMD)
    echo $result
}

function shadow(){
    status=$(getStatus)
    if [ $status = "running" ]
        then
        _printConfig
    else
        _log "Not runnning, starting ...\n"
        start
        sleep 5
        shadow
    fi
}

function _printConfig(){
    IP=$(getIp)
    _log "Using IP: $IP\n"      
    FILE="/etc/shadowsocks/aws.json"
    cat >tmpfile.tmp <<EOL 
{
    "server":"$IP",
    "server_port":8000,
    "password":"PASS",
    "method":"aes-256-cfb",
    "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "local_port":1180,
    "timeout":300,
    "fast_open": false,
    "workers": 1,
    "prefer_ipv6": false
}   
EOL
    _log "Writing Config\n"
    sudo mv tmpfile.tmp $FILE 
    _log "Starting ShadowsSocks\n"
    sudo systemctl restart shadowsocks@aws
}

if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
    _log "\n Possible commands: status|start|stop|ip|shadow \n\n"
else
    if [ $1 = "start" ] 
        then
        start
    elif [ $1 = "stop" ] 
        then
        stop
    elif [ $1 = "status" ] 
        then
        getStatus   
    elif [ $1 = "ip" ]
        then
        getIp
    elif [ $1 = "shadow" ]
        then
        shadow
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the repo below, you will love it.

- https://github.com/alexzhangs/aws-cfn-vpn

It leverages many tools to reduce the costs of maintaining VPN services within the AWS cloud. In the short words:

- AWS Config: used to capture the instances change.
- AWS Lambda: used to apply the change.
- Celery: used to do the heartbeat on the Shadowsocks nodes, and maintain SS ports on the fly.
- name.com API: used to push the DNS records to the DNS server.

Once it set up you are nearly hands-free, even you can have a scheduled job to replace the IP address of the Shadowsocks nodes.